Implementing Secure Key Management for IoT Devices with Hyperledger Fabric
I'm working on a project that involves integrating Hyperledger Fabric with IoT devices, and I'm currently facing challenges with implementing key management on the devices. I've researched various resources, but I'm still unsure about the best practices and how to proceed.I've been browsing through the documentation for Hyperledger Fabric, but I'm still struggling to grasp how to effectively utilize blockchain technology for managing keys in an IoT system. Despite my efforts, I haven't been able to find suitable content on GitHub either.
Specifically, I need guidance on how to securely generate and manage keys on IoT devices within a Hyperledger Fabric network. Are there any tutorials, guides, or recommended approaches that you could share with me?I'm reaching out to see if anyone can recommend any projects or resources that focus on integrating Hyperledger Fabric with IoT systems and specifically address key management. I'm eager to learn more about best practices and implementation strategies in this area.
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
